# Create table in mysql with one column containing sum of another two columns value

Tags: mysql, create-table

Is it possible in mysql to create a table with a column that combines two column values? something like this:

```
create table test1 (
    number1 int,
    number2 int,
    total int DEFAULT (number1+number2)
);
```

or like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `Result` (
    `aCount` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `bCount` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `cCount` =  `aCount` + `bCount`
);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not possible to do that exactly, but you can create a view based on a query that combines them:

```
CREATE VIEW `my_wacky_view` AS
SELECT `number1`, `number2`, `number1` + `number2` AS `total`
FROM `test1`;
```

I would avoid actually storing the combined data in a table, unless you're going to be running lots of queries that will reference the combined data in their WHERE clauses.

Comment: I suspect that many reads could be served well using query cache. Though, measure first :)

Comment: +1 views are underrated IMHO. I really like the way they capture column calculation, instead of having to repeat it in every select. They also stack up really well (ie view on views etc).

Comment: I would always use either a VIEW like this or a `SELECT num1+num2 FROM test` in my queries. Thinking about Computed columns (or using Triggers in MySQL) would be after the table has grown too big (millions of rows) and queries start to become slow. Or if the computation is very complex and not a simple addition/multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a trigger on the table so MySQL calculates and automatically inserts that column value every time an INSERT happens on your test1 table. Make the table:

```
create table test1 (
    number1 int,
    number2 int,
    number3 int
);
```

Then create a Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER INSERT
ON test1
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE test1 SET NEW.number3=NEW.number1+NEW.number2
```

MySQL documentation on triggers:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Make sure to add the ON UPDATE trigger as well if you expect UPDATES to happen to the rows.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well. From Edgar Velasquez' answer here, and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823477/164611), I stumbled upon this incantation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_t BEFORE INSERT
ON test1
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.number3=NEW.number1+NEW.number2;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_t_two BEFORE UPDATE
ON test1
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.number3=NEW.number1+NEW.number2;
```

This works for me on MySQL 5.6.22.

Answer (score 0):

Little fix :

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername BEFORE INSERT
ON test1
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.number3=NEW.number1+NEW.number2
```

Comment: Why is this considered a fix?