# evaluate expression in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with column a,b, expr  that expr is an expression from other column.
for example table contains

```
a   b   expr
------------
2   5   a+b
3   4   a*b+3
```

I like simply run a query and get flowing result:

```
a | b | expr 
------------ 
2 | 5 | 7 
3 | 4 | 15
```

I search doc for function, procedure etc, but i can't do it.
please help me!

Comment: do you want to achieve this when querying for data? Or when you insert the data

Comment: I don't think this is possible within only plain sql.
Maybe some kind of stored procedure will make it possible. I would advise to move this kind of abstraction to a programming language.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805498/create-table-in-mysql-with-one-column-containg-sum-of-another-two-columns-value)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I made for **fun**. Consider solving this with a real programming language, if this is not a one time thing to do.

```
drop table if exists Table1;
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`a` int, `b` int, `expr` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`a`, `b`, `expr`)
VALUES
    (2, 5, 'a+b'),
    (3, 4, 'a*b +3')
;

drop table if exists Table2;
CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`a` int, `b` int, `expr` int)
;

drop procedure if exists curdemo;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE seqel VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO Table2 (a, b, expr) SELECT a, b, ' , expr, ' FROM (SELECT ', a, ' as a, ', b, ' as b) sq;') FROM Table1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO seqel;
    IF NOT done THEN
       SET @sql:=seqel;
       PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
       EXECUTE stmt;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL curdemo();

SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Comment: thanks @tombom, your solution worked! but it is not simple and i can not use it.

Comment: my input table is large and every time i need only some row, and a multi thread program get that query, So if i use your program, i had to save result to separate tables(or in one table with a new column). it reduce efficiency. i search for a simple efficiency solution.

Comment: You won't find one with pure SQL. This is not what databases are made for. Use PHP or something.

Comment: @saeidArianpour And just to be clear, my solution is a one time thing, because it's simply not efficient. If you don't insert more rows into your table, you don't have to do this all over again. Then you simply `SELECT whatever FROM Table2;` Just wanted to make sure, this is clear.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood your question correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT a, b, (a+b) AS expr FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: no,it's not what i want. expr differ in rows for example next row expr=a*b+3

Comment: I think this is what he wants, except for that the expr can be variable. e.g. expr="(a % b)" or expr="(a*b)"

Comment: @saied Arianpour : You should explain this more clearly in your question. We don't understand that you want a different expression for each row

Comment: Well, my friend, as far as i know, you cant really do that without a given set of rules, that follow some kind of logic, and as Frédéric suggested, be more specific with your question please.

Comment: ok, select a,b,expr from mytable return  2,5,a+b   i like to run a query and it return 2,5,7

Comment: I think im starting to get your question, you want that what ever is stored in your expr table to be applied to the values of the col a and col b, and display it in your expr collumn. Am i right ?

Comment: yes,you know that expr may differ in each row, for example next row may contain :a*b

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I like the smiley more :P :) yes, basically in every programming language, the first and most basic rule is, if you can imagine it, you can code it, taking a question to the letter is a different thing thou.