# select the contents of the row based on the formula in column

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure where to start with this... Ive looked up computed columns but was unsure if this question fits.

I have a mysql table with the following details

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text,
  `conditions` text,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `algorithm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

In the column `algorithm` I have the value for this particular row

```
(SUM(Table1.ndr + Table2.ndr) * Table3.commission) > 400
```

(this value/forumula could possibly change per row)

Is there a way to select the contents of the row based on the formula in column `algorithm`?

Comment: can you give an example of how exactly will you be selecting row contents based on the algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to create a procedure to evaluate this expression. As your expression involves more than just maths you will need to have some kind of dictionary.

An example of how to do it (but not for your question) would be this: [Evaluate Expression in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046001/evaluate-expression-in-mysql)