# Use mysql row value as mysql operator

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I got values I wish to use as operators:

```
+ value 1 + value 2 + operator +
| --------+---------+----------|
| value 1 | value 2 |    =     |
| value 3 | value 4 |    >     |
| value 5 | value 6 |    <     |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

I was wondering if it is possible to write a query using the `operator` column as the operator for `WHERE` clause, for example like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 table2 operatorTable
WHERE `table1`.`id` `operatorTable`.`operator` `table2`.`id`
```

The `operatorTable.operator` in this query is to be substituted by `=`, `>` or `<` respectively.

I mean, I know how to do that in PHP and all that, but I'd like to use strictly MySQL :)

The goal is to achieve the maximum speed of the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [evaluate expression in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046001/evaluate-expression-in-mysql)

Comment: @OscarPérez ... is not

Comment: Well, its almost the same... both questions ask about a way to evaluate an expression that is stored as text in database, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CASE operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 table2 operatorTable
WHERE 
  CASE `operatorTable`.`operator`
     when  '<' then `table1`.`id` < `table2`.`id`
     when  '=' then `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`
     when  '>' then `table1`.`id` > `table2`.`id`
  END CASE
```

(Not tested, but it should work)

Answer (score 1):

Without using a function the only way I can think of doing it would be using 3 UNIONed queries:-

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 table2 operatorTable
WHERE `operatorTable`.`operator` = '='
AND `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table1 table2 operatorTable
WHERE `operatorTable`.`operator` = '<'
AND `table1`.`id` < `table2`.`id`
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table1 table2 operatorTable
WHERE `operatorTable`.`operator` = '>'
AND `table1`.`id` > `table2`.`id`
```