# UPDATE Same Row After UPDATE in Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want the `epc` column to always be `earnings`/`clicks`. I am using an AFTER UPDATE trigger to accomplish this. So if I were to add 100 clicks to this table, I would want the EPC to update automatically.

I am trying this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `records_integrity` AFTER UPDATE ON `records` FOR EACH ROW SET 
NEW.epc=IFNULL(earnings/clicks,0);
```

And getting this error:

```
MySQL said: #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger
```

I tried using OLD as well but also got an error. I could do BEFORE but then if I added 100 clicks it would use the previous # clicks for the trigger (right?)

What should I do to accomplish this?

EDIT - An example of a query that would be run on this:

```
UPDATE records SET clicks=clicks+100
//EPC should update automatically
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't update rows in the table in an *after* update trigger.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `records_integrity` BEFORE UPDATE
ON `records`
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.epc=IFNULL(new.earnings/new.clicks, 0);
```

EDIT:

Inside a trigger, you have have access to `OLD` and `NEW`.  `OLD` are the old values in the record and `NEW` are the new values.  In a *before* trigger, the `NEW` values are what get written to the table, so you can modify them.  In an *after* trigger, the `NEW` values have already been written, so they cannot be modified.  I think the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) explains this pretty well.

Comment: @hellohellosharp . . . Somehow it wasn't when I looked at the code. ;)

Comment: Thanks for updating - your answer appears to be working. I am confused though...wouldn't a BEFORE update use the wrong values for clicks and earnings?

Comment: @hellohellosharp . . . That is the difference between `old` and `new`.  The `set` is using the `new` values.

Comment: Makes sense...and I will accept your answer ASAP. I guess I don't understand how a `BEFORE` statement would know the `NEW` values.

Comment: How i can do a WHERE id=id after SET statemnent?

Comment: @KingsleyChew . . .You should ask a new question as a question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write two separate statements in that transaction

```
 update record set clicks=...

 update record set epc=...
```

or you could put them inside a function, say updateClick() and just call that function. By doing it this way you can easily alter your logic should the need arise.

Putting the logic inside a trigger might create a situation where debugging and tracing are made unnecessarily complex.