# Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, runtime-error, insertafter

Why do I get an error using this *trigger*?

```
CREATE TRIGGER save_Assignee AFTER INSERT ON changeitem
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SET new.assignee = (
        SELECT assignee
        FROM jiraissue INNER JOIN changegroup ON jiraissue.ID = changegroup.issueid
    )
END
```

Error message:

> #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Answer (score 14):

That is correct.  You need a `before insert` trigger if you want to modify the data:

```
create TRIGGER save_Assignee BEFORE INSERT ON changeitem FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.assignee = (select assignee
                        from jiraissue INNER JOIN
                             changegroup
                             ON jiraissue.ID = changegroup.issueid
                       )
END
```

As suggested by the name, the *AFTER* insert trigger is run *after* the data has been updated.  So, if you want to update the same row, use a *before* trigger.

Your subquery looks suspicious because it is not correlated with `new` and it looks like it could return more than one row.

Comment: same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823457/update-same-row-after-update-in-trigger