# How do I update a column based on the previous value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have read a lot of answers here but I couldn't adapt to my needs.

I have this table below where I would like to update the `BALANCE` column:

`balance = old.balance + new.amount`

```
+----+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| ID | TRANSACTION_ID | BANK_ID | ACCOUNT_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | CREATED             | DESCRIPTION      | AMOUNT | CURRENCY | BALANCE |
+----+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
|  1 | T1             |       2 |          2 |           1 | 2018-04-22 00:00:00 | TRANSACTION TEST | 100.00 | GBP      |    NULL |
|  2 | T2             |       2 |          2 |           1 | 2018-04-22 00:00:00 | TRANSACTION TEST | 125.00 | GBP      |    NULL |
|  3 | T3             |       2 |          2 |           1 | 2018-04-22 00:00:00 | TRANSACTION TEST | -73.00 | GBP      |    NULL |
+----+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

This is the result I would like is shown below:
I got it executing:

```
SET @balance:=0;
UPDATE TRANSACTIONS SET BALANCE = (@balance := @balance + AMOUNT) WHERE ID > 0;
```

There is no way to fire the statement above after a new column inserted?

```
+----+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| ID | TRANSACTION_ID | BANK_ID | ACCOUNT_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | CREATED             | DESCRIPTION      | AMOUNT | CURRENCY | BALANCE |
+----+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
|  1 | T1             |       2 |          2 |           1 | 2018-04-22 00:00:00 | TRANSACTION TEST | 100.00 | GBP      |  100.00 |
|  2 | T2             |       2 |          2 |           1 | 2018-04-22 00:00:00 | TRANSACTION TEST | 125.00 | GBP      |  225.00 |
|  3 | T3             |       2 |          2 |           1 | 2018-04-22 00:00:00 | TRANSACTION TEST | -73.00 | GBP      |  152.00 |
+----+----------------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

I tried using trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER updateBalance AFTER INSERT ON TRANSACTIONS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.BALANCE = BALANCE + NEW.AMOUNT;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

And I got the error:

`Error Code: 1362. Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger`

I am new in SQL and MySQL and I believe this is a common task for advanced users.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  A trigger is not going to change existing data in the table.  It doesn't produce results.

Comment: Do you have an idea using generated column? Tks

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried what you answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823457/update-same-row-after-update-in-trigger). It is not working ;/

Answer (score 0):

Values that can be calculated from other (materialized) values shouldn't be materialized as this can lead to inconsistencies.

Remove the column all together.

```
ALTER TABLE transactions
            DROP balance;
```

And create a view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW transactions_with_balance
AS
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT sum(t2.amount)
               FROM transactions t2
               WHERE t2.bank_id = t1.bank_id
                     AND t2.account_id = t1.account_id
                     AND t2.id <= t1.id) balance
       FROM transactions t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4028675c094f907720ecf5fb001b5ae5)

If you're using MySQL version 8 or higher you can also replace the subquery by the windowed version of `sum()`

```
CREATE VIEW transactions_with_balance
AS
SELECT t1.*,
       sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bank_id,
                                      t1.account_id
                         ORDER BY t1.id) balance
       FROM transactions t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43c279792eb8a947612a672ef2cc35f1)

The column `customer_id` also seems misplaced in the table as I suppose there is an account table where the customer that account belongs to is stored in a foreign key to the customer table. So you can get the customer via the `accoount_id`.

Comment: Tks, but there is no way to execute this  ````SET @balance:=0;
 UPDATE TRANSACTIONS SET BALANCE = (@balance := @balance + AMOUNT) WHERE ID > 0;````??

Comment: Sure you can execute that. But not in a trigger an the table. And it doesn't change that your on a dangerous path there...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, summing all the transaction amounts for the given `CUSTOMER_ID` and adding the new `AMOUNT` value to get the balance:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateBalance BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.BALANCE = NEW.AMOUNT +
                     COALESCE((SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) 
                               FROM transactions 
                               WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = NEW.CUSTOMER_ID), 0);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w7VCDynNGoex1VwAE6xH28/0)

Note you may want to further qualify the sum with

```
AND BANK_ID = NEW.BANK_ID
```

and/or

```
AND ACCOUNT_ID = NEW.ACCOUNT_ID
```

as necessary to distinguish exactly which records to read the previous transactions from.