# MySQL Computed Column equivalent to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In SQL server there are computed columns that we can use to insert some value which manipulate from another column value.

in SQL server we can write like this..

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products 
(
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , QtyAvailable smallint
  , UnitPrice money
  , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
);
```

But in MySQL how can I perform it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create table in mysql with one column containg sum of another two columns value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805498/create-table-in-mysql-with-one-column-containg-sum-of-another-two-columns-value) ... this post discusses a sum in `CREATE TABLE` but I expect it be equally valid for a product.

Comment: But that question not have the answer for my question.. it' says this is impossible but I think It's possible

Comment: If the post is correct, and I assume it is, you _can't_ have a computed column in MySQL with `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: There is no way to create computed column in MySQL, Instead you can try creating `view` over that table to compute the column value.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways to do that

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
     ProductID int NOT NULL,
     QtyAvailable smallint,
     UnitPrice DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
     InventoryValue1 decimal(10,2) AS (QtyAvailable * UnitPrice) VIRTUAL,
     InventoryValue2 DECIMAL(10,2) AS (QtyAvailable * UnitPrice) PERSISTENT
);
```

**Persistent**

is a real column that calculated and you can create a index on it

**VIRTUAL**

is calculated every time you get it

(This is apply for MySQL Server version 5.7.5 and above)

I use MariaDB and it start there with Version 5.2

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/

Comment: As I found this option is available in MySQL server version 5.7.5 on wards. Is it true?

Comment: MariaDB 5.2 contains features that didn't have time to go into MariaDB 5.1. For all practical purposes it's a drop in replacement for MariaDB 5.1 (and thus MySQL 5.1).