# Arithmetic Operations on database field

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `oyscat`.`chem_dept` (
`name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`matric_no` VARCHAR( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
`chm101` INT NOT NULL ,
`phs101` INT NOT NULL ,
`gns101` INT NOT NULL ,
`bio101` INT NOT NULL ,
`gns102` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This fields are going to receive marks scored in these courses,
How can I make this mysql command to add all the scores and place it in another field in the same record

Comment: You will have to use a procedure. Or a trigger maybe

Comment: This question is already asked refer the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805498/create-table-in-mysql-with-one-column-containg-sum-of-another-two-columns-value