# Achieve dynamic ranking structure for sql data on a web page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL data displayed on a web page and I want to create a dynamic ranking structure for that data. The data will be updated as the new user logs in and updates his data and structure has to update their ranks based on their scores. Like, there are around 20 rows for each user and all the fields of one row should be compared with all the other users' rows and do it for all the rows and update the ranking system.

I have tried checking SQL ranking functions but they were limited to one row, do not know if there are any other options to try them out or there is a completely different way around.

```
        <tr>
          <th>Kanto</th>
          <th>Johto</th>
          <th>Hoenn</th>
          <th>Sinnoh</th>
          <th>Collector</th>
          <th>Scientist</th>
          <th>Backpacker</th>
          <th>Battle Girl</th>
          <th>Berry Master</th>
          <th>Gym Leader</th>
          <th>Idol</th>
          <th>Great League Veteran</th>
          <th>Ultra League Veteran</th>
          <th>Master League Veteran</th>
          <th>Jogger</th>
          <th>Breeder</th>
          <th>Pikachu Fan</th>
          <th>Champion</th>
          <th>Battle Legend</th>
          <th>Pokemon Ranger</th>
          <th>Gentleman</th>
          <th>Pilot</th>
          <th>Fisherman</th>
          <th>Ace Trainer</th>
          <th>Youngster</th>
          <th>Cameraman</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * from user") or die($con->error());
        $i=0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['kanto']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['johto']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['hoenn']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['sinnoh']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['collector']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['scientist']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['backpacker']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['battle_girl'];; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['berry_master']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['gym_leader']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['idol']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['great_league_veteran']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ultra_league_veteran']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['master_league_veteran'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['jogger']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['breeder']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['pikachu_fan']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['champion']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['battle_legend']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['pokemon_ranger']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['gentleman']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['pilot']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['fisherman']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['ace_trainer']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['youngster']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['cameraman']; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
        } ?>
      </table>
```

So, above is my table showing data. All the fields are numbers and I want the data to be structured dynamically considering all the values from all the rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's wrong with using "order by"?

Comment: order by does not work as there are so many rows, need something that works for all the values of all rows.

Comment: oh I see.  Howevr,  you could create a dynamic column in your tables that automatically calculates the total of the row.   Then when you query it, you can sort by that "summed" total

Comment: note, apparently you will have to do that as a view.   See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6805526/3044080

Comment: it can also be done as a trigger, which would truly be dynamic.   This way, if someone updates a value, it would trigger a calculation which would then populate that column

Comment: okay, let me tell you how this has to work. Every row has values and each user has a specific value. values of specific row have to be sorted and the same applies to all the rows. After sorting all the values of all the rows ranking has to be made. Ranking should be done for users based on their values with other users.

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: @RakibulIslam I don't know what do you mean by table structure. But I use phpmyadmin for my database. Let me know how to find table structure if that can be of any help.

Comment: I want to see user table

Comment: here it is http://saiviru.in/else/random/user.pdf, don't know if this is the one

Comment: I would start by revising my schema.

Comment: `values of specific row have to be sorted and the same applies to all the rows. `  - so you want them to appear left to right in order of sort?  that's a bit complicated.  We can easily add a summed column (as mentioned above), and then sort by that, so the user with the highest total score of each of those columns will appear descending, top to bottom.  Is that what you want?